# Answer returning 0

Tags: java, double

Total beginner in Java.  My result keeps turning up as 0 where I want it to turn up as membercount * members (ie if there are 100 members and the weather = 1, the total should be 25).  I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.  I figure I'm not properly having my program store the information entered by the user so the doubles keep reading as 0.  Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package playgolf;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * @author Alex
 */
public class PlayGolf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        golf stats = new golf();
        stats.getData();
        golf total = new golf();
        total.display_data();
    }
}

class golf {
    private double members;
    private double weather;
    private double temp;
    private double membercount;
    public double total;

    public void getData() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many members are there?: ");
        members = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What is the weather like? (Enter 1 for sunny, 2 for overcast, 3 for rain): ");
        weather = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What is the temperature? (in Farenheight): ");
        temp = input.nextInt();

        if (weather == 1) {
            membercount = .25;
            if (weather == 2) {
                membercount = .12;
                if (weather == 3) {
                    membercount = .03;
                }
            }
        }
        if (temp < 32) {
            membercount = 0;
            System.out.println("No one will play today, it's too darn cold!");
        }
        total = (membercount * members);
    }

    public void display_data() {
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("This many members will play today: ");
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not entering in the `if(temp < 32)` condition? Because that makes total 0.

Comment: @Xelad1: did the answers help you? Some follow-up is appreciated. (For example, [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bug 1

The code blocks related to your weather logic are messed up; the closing braces are in the wrong place.

Properly indented, your code looks like this:

```
if (weather == 1) {
    membercount = .25;

    if (weather == 2) {
        membercount = .12;

        if (weather == 3) {
            membercount = .03;
        }

    }

 }
```

Now you can probably already see the bug. If `weather` is 2, the `weather == 2` condition will never be reached (`weather` cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time).

Corrected version:

```
 if (weather == 1) {
     membercount = .25;
 } 
 else if (weather == 2) {
     membercount = .12;
 }
 else if (weather == 3) {
     membercount = .03;
 }
```

### Bug 2

Another bug is in the main method. You should call `display_data()` **on the same object** as `getData()`. This would work:

```
golf stats = new golf();
stats.getData();
stats.display_data();
```

### Other problems & style issues

- `display_data` is not idiomatic Java method name. Should be `displayData`.
- Likewise, Java class names should start with uppercase letter. `Golf`, not `golf`. See e.g. [this guide on Java naming conventions](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html).
- It's suspicious to use `double` to represent one of three possible values (`weather`). Use `int`, or better yet, an `enum`. Also for `members` it is a pretty odd choice of type.

Answer (score 4):

You create new object again, it should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       golf stats = new golf();
       stats.getData();
       stats.display_data();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `if` conditions are nested, if `weather != 1`, the checks for `weather == 2` and `weather == 3` are never reached.

As a consequence, `membercount` is never set and takes the value of zero, yielding your zero result for `total`.

You should just have something like the following:

```
        switch (weather) {
        case 1:
            membercount = .25;
            break;
        case 2:
            membercount = .12;
            break;
        case 3:
            membercount = .03;
            break;
        default:
            // Do nothing or, better yet, produce an error
        }

        if (temp < 32) {
        // ...
```

You could simply use a series of `if`s, or an if-else chain. I'm using a switch because it's the safest choice in this case. This assumes that you change `weather` to be an `int`, which is actually preferable given your use of the variable. You should also esplicitly initialize the value of `weather` during declaration (or in the constructor, as you see fit):

```
private int weather = 0;
```

As pointed out by the other answers, you have a secondary bug in your listing: you should create only one object and have both calls on that, as follows:

```
   golf stats = new golf();
   stats.getData();
   stats.display_data();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getData()` on one instance (of `golf`) and calling `display_data()` on another one. The `stats` collects data, but the `total` does not. Try to call `display_data()` on `stats` instance / or call `getData()` on `total` instance / or use shared members (`static`s I mean).

```
golf stats = new golf();
stats.getData();
stats.display_data();
```

or

```
golf total = new golf();
total.getData();
total.display_data();
```